# .htaccess to exclude folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

my root folder do have following .htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On


    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301] 


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .* loader.php [L,QSA]



</IfModule>
```

i want to exclude the folder of siteadmin from the rule of RewriteRule .* loader.php [L,QSA] on root folder

inside subfolder: "siteadmin" i do have another .htaccess files like this:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "siteadmin"
AuthUserFile "/home/user1/.htpasswds/public_html/siteadmin/passwd"
require valid-user
```

loader.php (on root directory):

```
<?php
//die('Only enable this script if you dont have support for MultiViews');
$relative = '';
$loaders  = array(
    'ajax' => 1,
    'album' => 1,
    'albums' => 1,
    'blog' => 1,
    'blogs' => 1,
    'captcha' => 1,
    'categories' => 1,
    'community' => 1,
    'confirm' => 1,
    'error' => 1,
    'feedback' => 1,
    'feeds' => 1,
    'game' => 1,
    'games' => 1,
    'index' => 1,
    'invite' => 1,
    'loader' => 1,
    'login' => 1,
    'logout' => 1,
    'lost' => 1,
    'mail' => 1,
    'notice' => 1,
    'notices' => 1,
    'photo' => 1,
    'requests' => 1,
    'search' => 1,
    'signup' => 1,
    'static' => 1,
    'stream' => 1,
    'upload' => 1,
    'user' => 1,
    'users' => 1,
    'video' => 1,
    'videos' => 1,
    'edit' => 1
);

$query      = ( isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ) ? $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : NULL;
$request    = str_replace($relative, '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$request    = str_replace('?' .$query, '', $request);
$request    = explode('/', trim($request, '/'));
if (isset($request['0'])) {
    $page   = $request['0'];
    if (isset($loaders[$page])) {
        require $page. '.php';
    } else {
        header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
        die();
    }
} else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    die();
}
?>
```

the loader.php does it job when i access the site like http://www.domain.com/signup
it will load signup.php

the siteadmin is still not able to use the password protect. is there anyway i can exclude the folder siteadmin from the loader.php rule?

Comment: If `siteadmin` is a real folder then having `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` is already skipping `loader.php` rule for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/siteadmin/?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ loader.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: that does not work, the password protect does not load if i open siteadmin. and i see 404 when access to siteadmin folder

Comment: Okay. A question : are the loader.php and .htaccess files in the root folder ?

Comment: And the .htaccess file and the siteadmin folder ?

Comment: i have .htaccess file on root directory and siteadmin folder

Comment: same no luck. Or if you can protect the subfolder from root directory's .htaccess is that possible? Instead of we put a .htaccess inside siteadmin folder.

Answer (score 0):

A database is usually recommended for the storage of users' login information, especially as the user membership grows.

To exclude **siteadmin** from the redirect specified above, you needn't worry about that. The code has these conditions

```
 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .* loader.php [L,QSA]
```

The first line says that if the request points to an actual file, the redirect should be ignored; the second line says that if the request points to an actual directory, the redirect should be ignored also. 
This means that whenever a file or directory (including siteadmin) is requested, the redirect will be ignored. That resolves your first problem  
 
For the second problem **(password protecting the folder)**, you need to verify that the **mod_auth** module is enabled. 
Put something like this into the .htaccess file in the siteadmin folder.

```
<IfModule mod_auth.c>
AuthType Basic
AuthName "siteadmin"
AuthUserFile "/home/user1/.htpasswds/public_html/siteadmin/passwd"
require valid-user
</IfModule>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: where do we put this:
<IfModule mod_auth.c>
AuthType Basic
AuthName "siteadmin"
AuthUserFile "/home/user1/.htpasswds/public_html/siteadmin/passwd"
require valid-user
</IfModule>

on root .htaccess or inside siteadmin folder's .htaccess?